# REST API call from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Dta Factory Question -
In REST API, I am getting bearer token(as POST operation) in POSTMAN & in Logic Apps after passing 
Content-Type & apikey in Header
client_id,client_secret,grant_type in body

For getting Bearer token in Azure Data Factory in Web activity i am passing 
Content-Type & apikey in Header

in body i am passing 
client_id:XXXX&
client_secret:XXXX&
grant_type:XXXX

and getting below error 
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "{\n   \"errors\" : [ {\n      \"message\": \"Unknown server error\",\n      \"type\": \"UnknownError\"\n   } ]\n}\n",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1"
}

Please help.

I referred 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c826f2a8-fa23-4513-bf72-51c97f36b407/the-format-of-body-for-a-post-request-in-web-activity-in-azure-data-factory?forum=AzureDataFactory

---

Azure Dta Factory Question - In REST API, I am getting bearer token(as POST operation) in POSTMAN & in Logic Apps after passing Content-Type & apikey in Header client_id,client_secret,grant_type in body

For getting Bearer token in Azure Data Factory in Web activity i am passing Content-Type & apikey in Header

in body i am passing

{ 
'client_id': 'XXX',
'client_secret': 'XXX',
'grant_type': 'XXX'
}

and getting below error

{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptableh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable

",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1"
}

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the client_secret you are passing. Declare one more parameter in the body that is Content-Type: application/json;